# How to extract data from an object in python

Tags: python, json

I am getting an exception which am transferring to a variable. The output of the variable is given below:

```
schema.SchemaError("Key 'policy' error:\nOr({'name': And(<class 'str'>, <built-in function len>), 'age': And(<class 'int'>, <function <lambda> at 0x000001C964E92DC8>), Optional('gender'): And(<class 'str'>, Use(<method 'lower' of 'str' objects>), <function <lambda> at 0x000001C964E92E58>)}) did not validate {'name': 'Sue', 'age': 28, 'gnder': 'Squid'}\nWrong key 'gnder' in {'name': 'Sue', 'age': 28, 'gnder': 'Squid'}")
```

Please let me know how I can get the contents of this variable, I could try to convert this into a string but then it becomes very cumbersome to extract the contents. I specifically want the contents after 'did not validate' part.

EDIT - Not looking to resolve the error, error was expected. I transferred the contents of the exception to a variable, just need to figure out how to read the variable.

Comment: Please provide a reduced version of the code that resulted in that error, and if possible also a minimized version of the input data.

Comment: Hey, am not looking to resolve the error, error was expected. I transferred the contents of the exception to a variable, just need to figure out how to read the variable.

Comment: does this help? [SchemaError](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/errors/#jsonschema.exceptions.SchemaError)

Comment: Nope the error is fine, am just unable to read the error, I want the contents of the error, currently its coming as a data type as shown above. I want to get which key was wrong from the error output.

Answer (score 2):

1. Store it in `variable`
2. Convert to `string`
3. Search for `did not validate` in the converted string
4. the string lies in `127`th position
5. search for `{` in the string as it is the starting after the error
6. takeout the thing after the `position`
7. convert it to any form you want
8. ALSO: print the variable `a` for confirmation
9. CODE :

```py
a = schema.SchemaError("Key 'policy' error:\nOr({'name': And(<class 'str'>, <built-in function len>), 'age': And(<class 'int'>, <function <lambda> at 0x000001C964E92DC8>), Optional('gender'): And(<class 'str'>, Use(<method 'lower' of 'str' objects>), <function <lambda> at 0x000001C964E92E58>)}) did not validate {'name': 'Sue', 'age': 28, 'gnder': 'Squid'}\nWrong key 'gnder' in {'name': 'Sue', 'age': 28, 'gnder': 'Squid'}")
a = str(a)
b = 127 #every error starts from here
a = a[b:len(a)]
c = a.find("{")
a = a[c:len(a)]
print(a)
```

Comment: Almost solved, getting this:  "{'name': 'Sue', 'age': 28, 'gnder': 'Squid'}\nWrong key 'gnder' in {'name': 'Sue', 'age': 28, 'gnder': 'Squid'}"
Any way I could convert this into a dictionary?

Comment: Cannot accept this as an answer as 'did not validate' string won't be there for every error, sometimes there is 'key not found', 'datatype wrong' etc.

Comment: @arunmenon Now the problem of other errors are solved ;)